# Django url redirect error

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following in my project urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^login$', user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$', user_logout, name='logout'),
)
```

and i had the following in my app urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.DefaultView.as_view(), name='default'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.CustomerRegister, name='customerregister'),
)
```

The default view loads up fine but the Register url is not working. I tried the following links:

```
localhost:8000/
localhost:8000/register
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')),` should be `url(r'', include('myapp.urls')),`

Note that the `^` matches the start of the string, and the `$` matches the end of the string, so `^$` will only match an empty string (usually used for the index). Similarly, notice the admin url does not end with a `$`.